# Кастомный селект не работает на некоторых пунктах

Tags: javascript

Я новичок, написал код, вроде все работает, потом увидел что на некотрых пунктах в конслоли выдает ошибку (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null")

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    const selected = document.querySelectorAll(".selected");
    const optionsContainer = document.querySelectorAll(".options-container");
    const optionsList = document.querySelectorAll(".option");

    selected.forEach((select) => {
        select.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
            optionsContainer.forEach((optionContainer) => {
                optionContainer.classList.remove("active");
            });

            e.target.previousElementSibling.classList.toggle("active");
        });
    });

    optionsList.forEach((option) => {
        option.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
            selected.forEach((select) => {
                // console.log(option.parentElement.parentElement);
                // console.log(select.parentElement);
                if (option.parentElement.parentElement == select.parentElement) {
                    select.innerHTML = e.target.querySelector("label").innerHTML;
                    optionsContainer.forEach((optionContainer) => {
                        optionContainer.classList.remove("active");
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

```css
/*! normalize.css v8.0.1 | MIT License | github.com/necolas/normalize.css */

/* Document
   ========================================================================== */

/**
 * 1. Correct the line height in all browsers.
 * 2. Prevent adjustments of font size after orientation changes in iOS.
 */

html {
    line-height: 1.15; /* 1 */
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; /* 2 */
}

/* Sections
     ========================================================================== */

/**
   * Remove the margin in all browsers.
   */

body {
    margin: 0;
}

/**
   * Render the `main` element consistently in IE.
   */

main {
    display: block;
}

/**
   * Correct the font size and margin on `h1` elements within `section` and
   * `article` contexts in Chrome, Firefox, and Safari.
   */

h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
    margin: 0.67em 0;
}

/* Grouping content
     ========================================================================== */

/**
   * 1. Add the correct box sizing in Firefox.
   * 2. Show the overflow in Edge and IE.
   */

hr {
    box-sizing: content-box; /* 1 */
    height: 0; /* 1 */
    overflow: visible; /* 2 */
}

/**
   * 1. Correct the inheritance and scaling of font size in all browsers.
   * 2. Correct the odd `em` font sizing in all browsers.
   */

pre {
    font-family: monospace, monospace; /* 1 */
    font-size: 1em; /* 2 */
}

/* Text-level semantics
     ========================================================================== */

/**
   * Remove the gray background on active links in IE 10.
   */

a {
    background-color: transparent;
}

/**
   * 1. Remove the bottom border in Chrome 57-
   * 2. Add the correct text decoration in Chrome, Edge, IE, Opera, and Safari.
   */

abbr[title] {
    border-bottom: none; /* 1 */
    text-decoration: underline; /* 2 */
    text-decoration: underline dotted; /* 2 */
}

/**
   * Add the correct font weight in Chrome, Edge, and Safari.
   */

b,
strong {
    font-weight: bolder;
}

/**
   * 1. Correct the inheritance and scaling of font size in all browsers.
   * 2. Correct the odd `em` font sizing in all browsers.
   */

code,
kbd,
samp {
    font-family: monospace, monospace; /* 1 */
    font-size: 1em; /* 2 */
}

/**
   * Add the correct font size in all browsers.
   */

small {
    font-size: 80%;
}

/**
   * Prevent `sub` and `sup` elements from affecting the line height in
   * all browsers.
   */

sub,
sup {
    font-size: 75%;
    line-height: 0;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

sub {
    bottom: -0.25em;
}

sup {
    top: -0.5em;
}

/* Embedded content
     ========================================================================== */

/**
   * Remove the border on images inside links in IE 10.
   */

img {
    border-style: none;
}

/* Forms
     ========================================================================== */

/**
   * 1. Change the font styles in all browsers.
   * 2. Remove the margin in Firefox and Safari.
   */

button,
input,
optgroup,
select,
textarea {
    font-family: inherit; /* 1 */
    font-size: 100%; /* 1 */
    line-height: 1.15; /* 1 */
    margin: 0; /* 2 */
}

/**
   * Show the overflow in IE.
   * 1. Show the overflow in Edge.
   */

button,
input {
    /* 1 */
    overflow: visible;
}

/**
   * Remove the inheritance of text transform in Edge, Firefox, and IE.
   * 1. Remove the inheritance of text transform in Firefox.
   */

button,
select {
    /* 1 */
    text-transform: none;
}

/**
   * Correct the inability to style clickable types in iOS and Safari.
   */

button,
[type="button"],
[type="reset"],
[type="submit"] {
    -webkit-appearance: button;
}

/**
   * Remove the inner border and padding in Firefox.
   */

button::-moz-focus-inner,
[type="button"]::-moz-focus-inner,
[type="reset"]::-moz-focus-inner,
[type="submit"]::-moz-focus-inner {
    border-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}

/**
   * Restore the focus styles unset by the previous rule.
   */

button:-moz-focusring,
[type="button"]:-moz-focusring,
[type="reset"]:-moz-focusring,
[type="submit"]:-moz-focusring {
    outline: 1px dotted ButtonText;
}

/**
   * Correct the padding in Firefox.
   */

fieldset {
    padding: 0.35em 0.75em 0.625em;
}

/**
   * 1. Correct the text wrapping in Edge and IE.
   * 2. Correct the color inheritance from `fieldset` elements in IE.
   * 3. Remove the padding so developers are not caught out when they zero out
   *    `fieldset` elements in all browsers.
   */

legend {
    box-sizing: border-box; /* 1 */
    color: inherit; /* 2 */
    display: table; /* 1 */
    max-width: 100%; /* 1 */
    padding: 0; /* 3 */
    white-space: normal; /* 1 */
}

/**
   * Add the correct vertical alignment in Chrome, Firefox, and Opera.
   */

progress {
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

/**
   * Remove the default vertical scrollbar in IE 10+.
   */

textarea {
    overflow: auto;
}

/**
   * 1. Add the correct box sizing in IE 10.
   * 2. Remove the padding in IE 10.
   */

[type="checkbox"],
[type="radio"] {
    box-sizing: border-box; /* 1 */
    padding: 0; /* 2 */
}

/**
   * Correct the cursor style of increment and decrement buttons in Chrome.
   */

[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
    height: auto;
}

/**
   * 1. Correct the odd appearance in Chrome and Safari.
   * 2. Correct the outline style in Safari.
   */

[type="search"] {
    -webkit-appearance: textfield; /* 1 */
    outline-offset: -2px; /* 2 */
}

/**
   * Remove the inner padding in Chrome and Safari on macOS.
   */

[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

/**
   * 1. Correct the inability to style clickable types in iOS and Safari.
   * 2. Change font properties to `inherit` in Safari.
   */

::-webkit-file-upload-button {
    -webkit-appearance: button; /* 1 */
    font: inherit; /* 2 */
}

/* Interactive
     ========================================================================== */

/*
   * Add the correct display in Edge, IE 10+, and Firefox.
   */

details {
    display: block;
}

/*
   * Add the correct display in all browsers.
   */

summary {
    display: list-item;
}

/* Misc
     ========================================================================== */

/**
   * Add the correct display in IE 10+.
   */

template {
    display: none;
}

/**
   * Add the correct display in IE 10.
   */

[hidden] {
    display: none;
}
body {
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    background: #f7f6ff;
}
.container {
    display: flex;
}
h2 {
    margin: 16px;
}
.select-container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 32px;
}
.select-box {
    display: flex;
    width: 400px;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.select-box .options-container {
    background: #2f3640;
    color: #f5f6fa;
    max-height: 0;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.4s;
    border-radius: 8px;
    overflow: hidden;
    order: 1;
}
.selected {
    background: #2f3640;
    border-radius: 8px;
    color: #f5f6fa;
    margin: 0px 0px 8px 0px;
    position: relative;
    order: 0;
}
.selected::after {
    content: "";
    background: url("img/arrow-down.svg");
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 32px;
    right: 10px;
    top: 5px;
    transition: all 0.4s;
}
.select-box .options-container.active {
    max-height: 240px;
    opacity: 1;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
.select-box .options-container.active + .selected::after {
    transform: rotateX(180deg);
    top: -6px;
}
.select-box .options-container::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 8px;
    background: #0d141f;
    border-radius: 0 8px 8px 0;
}
.select-box .options-container::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #525861;
    border-radius: 0 8px 8px 0;
}
.select-box .option,
.selected {
    padding: 12px 24px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.select-box .option:hover {
    background: #414b57;
}
.select-box label {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.select-box .option .radio {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css" />
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="select-container">
                <h2>Category</h2>
                <div class="select-box">
                    <div class="options-container">
                        <div class="option">
                            <input type="radio" class="radio" id="auto" name="category" />
                            <label for="auto">Automobiles</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="option">
                            <input type="radio" class="radio" id="film" name="category" />
                            <label for="film">Film</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="option">
                            <input type="radio" class="radio" id="science" name="category" />
                            <label for="science">Science</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="option">
                            <input type="radio" class="radio" id="art" name="category" />
                            <label for="art">Art</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="option">
                            <input type="radio" class="radio" id="music" name="category" />
                            <label for="music">Music</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="option">
                            <input type="radio" class="radio" id="travel" name="category" />
                            <label for="travel">Travel</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="option">
                            <input type="radio" class="radio" id="sport" name="category" />
                            <label for="sport">Sport</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="option">
                            <input type="radio" class="radio" id="news" name="category" />
                            <label for="news">News</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="option">
                            <input
                                type="radio"
                                class="radio"
                                id="tutorials"
                                name="category"
                            />
                            <label for="tutorials">Tutorials</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="selected">Select Category</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="select-container">
                <h2>Category</h2>
                <div class="select-box">
                    <div class="options-container">
                        <div class="option">
                            <input type="radio" class="radio" id="auto" name="category" />
                            <label for="auto">Automobiles</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="option">
                            <input type="radio" class="radio" id="film" name="category" />
                            <label for="film">Film</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="option">
                            <input type="radio" class="radio" id="science" name="category" />
                            <label for="science">Science</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="option">
                            <input type="radio" class="radio" id="art" name="category" />
                            <label for="art">Art</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="option">
                            <input type="radio" class="radio" id="music" name="category" />
                            <label for="music">Music</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="option">
                            <input type="radio" class="radio" id="travel" name="category" />
                            <label for="travel">Travel</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="option">
                            <input type="radio" class="radio" id="sport" name="category" />
                            <label for="sport">Sport</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="option">
                            <input type="radio" class="radio" id="news" name="category" />
                            <label for="news">News</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="option">
                            <input
                                type="radio"
                                class="radio"
                                id="tutorials"
                                name="category"
                            />
                            <label for="tutorials">Tutorials</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="selected">Select Category</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="select-container">
                <h2>Category</h2>
                <div class="select-box">
                    <div class="options-container">
                        <div class="option">
                            <input type="radio" class="radio" id="auto" name="category" />
                            <label for="auto">Automobiles</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="option">
                            <input type="radio" class="radio" id="film" name="category" />
                            <label for="film">Film</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="option">
                            <input type="radio" class="radio" id="science" name="category" />
                            <label for="science">Science</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="option">
                            <input type="radio" class="radio" id="art" name="category" />
                            <label for="art">Art</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="option">
                            <input type="radio" class="radio" id="music" name="category" />
                            <label for="music">Music</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="option">
                            <input type="radio" class="radio" id="travel" name="category" />
                            <label for="travel">Travel</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="option">
                            <input type="radio" class="radio" id="sport" name="category" />
                            <label for="sport">Sport</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="option">
                            <input type="radio" class="radio" id="news" name="category" />
                            <label for="news">News</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="option">
                            <input
                                type="radio"
                                class="radio"
                                id="tutorials"
                                name="category"
                            />
                            <label for="tutorials">Tutorials</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="selected">Select Category</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Фикс: `e.target.querySelector("label")` ▶ `e.target.closest('option').querySelector('label')`

Comment: А вообще - тут на самом деле "все неправильно" Ⓒ